# How can i put each column data to different arrays fetching data from database

Tags: php, arrays

I have a four different tables which have one of the fields as loc1, loc2, loc3, loc4. I am fetching data from database using a procedure from these tables which uses one parameter. I want that every column data when fetched must be saved in a different array i.e loc1 field data in $loc1 array, loc2 field data in $loc2 array and same for other fields. My code is as.

```
$sql = "call report_card_seven_five_three_one_two('" .id. "')";
$loc1 = array();
$loc2 = array();
$loc3 = array();
$loc4 = array();

if (mysqli_multi_query($connection, $sql)) {                              
     while ($row =mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
       {
        while($row =mysql_fetch_array($result))                   
          {


          }
       }
    mysqli_free_result($result);    
   while(mysqli_next_result($connection) && mysqli_more_results($connection));
}
```

Can any one help me on this part.

Answer (score 1):

May be like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
     if(!empty($row['loc1']) || $row['loc1'] != NULL || $row['loc1'] != "")
      {
             array_push($loc1, $row['loc1']);
      }

     if(!empty($row['loc2']) || $row['loc2'] != NULL || $row['loc2'] != "")
       {
             array_push($loc2, $row['loc2']);
       }

       if(!empty($row['loc3']) || $row['loc3'] != NULL || $row['loc3'] != "")
       {
           array_push($loc3, $row['loc3']);
       }

       if(!empty($row['loc4']) || $row['loc4'] != NULL || $row['loc4'] != "")
       {
         array_push($loc4,$row['loc4']);                                             
       }                                                    
    }
```